# Change innerHTML with "querySelectorAll(".className")[x].innerHTML" checking what span index was clicked

Tags: javascript, html, indexing

I'm looking to change the **Span text** using javascript with **document.querySelectorAll(".className")[x].innerHTML** where "**x**" is the Span index position clicked but I don't find how. Thank you

**HTML EXAMPLE**

```
<div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 1</span>
<div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 2</span>
<div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 3</span>

<textarea id="text" aria-required="true">CONTENT</textarea>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var item = document.getElementById( 'text' );
document.querySelectorAll(".field")[0].innerHTML = item.value; //The 0 should be the index of the span clicked
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
<div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 1</span>
<div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 2</span>
<div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 3</span>
<textarea id="text" aria-required="true">CONTENT</textarea>


<script>

document.querySelectorAll(".field").forEach(function (element) {
    element.nextElementSibling.addEventListener("click", function () {
        element.nextElementSibling.innerText = 
        document.getElementById('text').value;
})})

</script>
```

**Update**

If you just want to remove `nextSiblingElement`, you can do something like this:-

```
<div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 1</span>
<div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 2</span>
<div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 3</span>
<textarea id="text" aria-required="true">CONTENT</textarea>


<script>

document.querySelectorAll("span").forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function () {
        element.innerText = 
        document.getElementById('text').value;
})})

</script>
```

**But, if there is a must for you to use indexes , try the following:-**

1. Using `for` loop but not indexes.

```
<div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 1</span>
<div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 2</span>
<div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 3</span>
<textarea id="text" aria-required="true">CONTENT</textarea>


<script>
var i;
for (i of document.querySelectorAll("span"))
i.addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.innerText = 
        document.getElementById('text').value;
})

</script>
```

2. Using indexes and `for` loop.

```
<div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 1</span>
<div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 2</span>
<div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 3</span>
<textarea id="text" aria-required="true">CONTENT</textarea>


<script>
var i;
var spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");

for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)
spans[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.innerText = 
        document.getElementById('text').value;
})

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Your code works great but I need to use indexes because the HTML EXAMPLE it just that and example html, there are a lot more DIVs on to solve my problem using nextElementSibling.

Comment: @Pedrinbeep, please review the answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! @user12137152

Comment: just one thing. You know why I need to click the span two times to make any on your solutions to work?

Comment: I have tried all of them. They all work with a single click. Their might some problem on your side. Please check by using someone else's device and please let me if I the code is still problematic.

Comment: I get an error with **document.getElementById('text').value;** getting **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"**. Without it and put on it a simple text like "Hello World!" solve that the problem

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use indexes, use [previousElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) instead. **The below has been updated to find the nearest previous sibling with the class "field"**

```js
//Get the spans
let spans = document.querySelectorAll("#target > span");
//For each span
for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  //Apply an event listener
  spans[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    elem = this;
    //Find the closest previous sibling with class field
    while((elem = elem.previousElementSibling) != null) {
      if(elem.classList.contains("field")){
        elem.innerText = document.getElementById("text").value;
        break;
      }       
    }        
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="target">
  <div>There is no previous viable div</div>
  <span>example 0</span>
  <div class="field"></div>
  <div>Don't change me</div>
  <span>example 1</span>
  <div class="field"></div>
  <span>example 2</span>
  <div class="field"></div>
  <span>example 3</span>
</div>

<textarea id="text" aria-required="true">CONTENT</textarea>
```

If you must use indexes you need to loop the spans to get the current index.

```js
//Get the spans
let spans = document.querySelectorAll("#target > span");
//Get the divs
let divs = document.querySelectorAll("#target .field"); //For each span
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  //Apply an event listener
  spans[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    //Loop the spans
    for (var s = 0; s < spans.length; s++) {
      //If we are at the clicked div
      if (spans[s] === this) {
        //Assign the text and break out of the loop
        divs[s].innerText = document.getElementById("text").value;
        break;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="target">
  <div class="field"></div>
  <span>example 1</span>
  <div class="field"></div>
  <span>example 2</span>
  <div class="field"></div>
  <span>example 3</span>
</div>
<textarea id="text" aria-required="true">CONTENT</textarea>
```

Better still add some logical grouping in your html, if you can, and take advantage of event bubbling.

```js
let groups = document.querySelectorAll("#target .group");
for (var i = 0 ; i < groups.length; i++) {
  groups[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
    //If a span is clicked 
    if(event.target.tagName === "SPAN"){
      //Assign the text 
      this.querySelector(".field").innerText = document.getElementById("text").value;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="target">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="field"></div>
    <span>example 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
<textarea id="text" aria-required="true">CONTENT</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I'm looking to use indexes because the HTML EXAMPLE it just that and example html of the my problem. Using previousElementSibling works great but not work in my case

Comment: Have you got leeway in refactoring the HTML, for exmple creating logical groupings using `divs`, otherwise there is no elegant way to grab the index of the clicked `span` without using a loop

Comment: I can't modify the HTML, I have not freedom on it. It is not a problem using a loop but I don't know how to check what **span** was clicked and then change the text from the **textarea**. Index was the only idea I have

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you're looking to create **reactivity:** when the textarea's content changes, some other element's text is modified. I'd recommend implementing this with an `input` element that monitors changes (you can use `.onchange` or `.onkeyup`, or `addEventListener()` to listen for events), and then updates another element with the value.

```js
document.querySelector("input").onkeyup = function (event) {document.querySelector("span").innerText = event.target.value}
```

```html
<input type="text"> <span>start typing...</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. You interpretation will be almost correct because you get the idea from the "textarea" and it is so interesting but is not what I looking for. In my case is changing the text of the span (with a lot of spans) without adapting the HTML or using any kind of ElementSibling, because the HTML is an example and the real one have more code.